# PHP Logix expression result to variable

Tags: php

Is it possible to return 'false' or 'true' with logic expression?
I need to put result to js ellegantly.

```
<script>
var asd = <?=(1==2)?>; // I want return var asd = false;
</script>
```

Comment: You need to echo a literal `false` or `true`: `var asd = <?= (1==2) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
var asd = <?=(1==2)?'true':'false'?>; // I want return var asd = false;
</script>
```

Comment: Yep, I just wanted to do code smaller. Anyway now I understood. Thanx!